# Configuring Web Applications for iOS

Tags: web-applications, metadata, pinned-site

I have something like this in head tag in index.html

```
    <!-- Pinned Website for Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 -->
    <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/img/tiny.png" />
    <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/img/square.png"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/img/wide.png"/>
    <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/img/large.png"/>
    <!-- Pinned Website for iOS -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/img/tiny.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/img/tiny.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/img/tiny.png">
    <!-- Pinned Website for Chrome on Android -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="196x196" href="/img/tiny.png">
```

For Android, we can use manifest while Windows we can use msapplication-config and xml file to make index.html tidier. My question is, do we have anything like this for iOS.